# React Native: Extra empty space on top of the screen

Tags: react-native

I have a bug where a user clicks on a survey and then opens up what is called supporting information that expands the UI further, then the user selects his or her answer and clicks on the NEXT QUESTION button, at that point the whole top part of the screen drops down exposing this huge gap. This is the code I believe governs all that behavior:

```
class BallotSurveyDetails extends PureComponent {
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.currentWizardPage !== this.props.currentWizardPage) {
      this.scroll.props.scrollToPosition(0, 0, true);
    }
  }

  render() {
    const {
      currentWizardPage,
      selectedSurvey,
      handleNextQuestionButtonPress,
      handleResponseChanged,
      loading,
      responses,
      handleSubmitButtonPress,
      saving,
      wizardPages
    } = this.props;
    if (!saving && loading) {
      return <Loading />;
    }

    const isWizard = selectedSurvey.Layout !== "Wizard";

    const isList = selectedSurvey.Layout !== "List";

    const displayNextQ = isWizard && currentWizardPage < wizardPages;

    const displaySubmit =
      isList || (isWizard && currentWizardPage === wizardPages);

    const sortedGroups = (selectedSurvey.QuestionGroups || []).sort(
      (a, b) => a.Order - b.Order
    );

    const wizardGroup = isWizard ? sortedGroups[currentWizardPage - 1] : null;
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        {isWizard && wizardPages.length > 1 && (
          <Card style={styles.pagination}>
            <RadioPagination
              numberOfPages={wizardPages}
              currentPage={currentWizardPage}
            />
          </Card>
        )}
        <KeyboardAwareScrollView
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          extraScrollHeight={45}
          innerRef={ref => {
            this.scroll = ref;
          }}
          enableOnAndroid={true}
          contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 90 }}
        >
          <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.ballotTitle}>{selectedSurvey.Name}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.ballotSubtitle}>
              {selectedSurvey.Description}
            </Text>
          </View>
          {isList &&
```

What I tried to do to resolve this was add `automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}` inside the `KeyboardAwareScrollView`, did nothing to resolve the bug. Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the appear is with this code snippet here:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.currentWizardPage !== this.props.currentWizardPage) {
      this.scroll.props.scrollToPosition(0, 0, true);
    }
  }
```

In particular, `this.scroll.props.scrollToPosition(0, 0, true);`. In removing the whole component lifecycle method, the bug went away.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's causing this for you, but here are a few things that have corrected similar problems I've had in the past:

1. It can help to wrap every screen in a container with flex:1.
2. I had a similar case with conditionally rendering a search bar above a FlatList and I used this to fix it:

I added this to the top of my file.

```
import { Dimensions, other stuff you need} from 'react-native';

const deviceHieght = Dimensions.get('window').height;
```

and then I wrapped my FlatList in a view like this

```
<View style={this.state.showBar === false ? styles.containFlatlist : styles.containSearchFlatlist}>
```

and this is the styling it was referencing

```
containFlatlist: {
  height: deviceHieght
},
containSearchFlatlist: {
  height: deviceHieght-100
},
```

3. In a different similar case I had an issue like this with a screen that displayed photos on click within a scrollview. In that case I did this:

   ```
             <ScrollView
             ref={component => this._scrollInput = component}
             >
   ```

Then in componentDidMount I put

```
setTimeout(() => {
this._scrollInput.scrollTo({ x: 0, animated: false })
}, 100)
```

I was also using react navigation in this case so I also did

```
                return(<View style={styles.mainFlex}>
              <NavigationEvents
          onWillBlur={payload => this._scrollInput.scrollTo({x:0})}
        />
```

Followed by the rest of my code.

I hope one of those helps. Given that you're also dealing with a scrollview, my best guess is that the third fix is most likely to work in your situation.

Comment: I tried implementing the above inside my `KeyboardAwareScrollView` but it did not work out for me. I am going to see if it makes sense to use it on the main `FlatList` that renders my activity feed, but not sure if that will take care of what is specifically going on in ballot survey details component.